# Getting the hour from a datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

How can I select the hour from a `datetime`?

I'm looking for the equivalent of Oracle's `TO_CHAR( d, 'HH24' )`, which would return `17` for `2010-06-23 17:22:31`.

---

I tried to find out about the best time (best answer/question-ration) to ask an `SQL`-related question on StackOverflow, using [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new). I got it to work, but I'm sure there is a more elegant version.

```
Select
  Left( Convert(VARCHAR(10), creationDate, 8 ), 2 ) As hour,
  Convert(Float, Count(*)) / Count(Distinct p.parentId) As ratio
From posts p
Join postTags pt On ( pt.postId = p.parentId )
Join tags t On ( t.id = pt.tagId )
Where p.postTypeId = 2 And t.tagName = '##TagName##'
Group By Left( Convert(VARCHAR(10), creationDate, 8 ), 2 )
Order BY hour
```

---

BTW, the best time seems to be between `15:00` and `16:00` - guess I'm asking too late :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql)

```
select DATEPART(hour, DateTimeField) as Hour from Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the DatePart() tsql function with the part ID of "hour"

Look at this for a good explanation

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186265

Comment: Thanks for the additional link (`+1`)

Comment: @PeterLang link is dead

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
SELECT DatePart(hh, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

`datepart(hh,dateColumn)` should get you the hour component for any datetime.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT HOUR(datetimefield) AS hour
```

The HOUR() function should do the job.
Source http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't seem to work. Looks like you are citing the `MySQL` documentation.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice you have a full datetime, though you only have time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DatePart(hh, CreationDate) As Hour
    , Convert(Float, Count(*)) / Count(Distinct p.parentId) As Ratio
From posts As p
    Join postTags As pt 
        On ( pt.postId = p.parentId )
    Join tags As t 
        On ( t.id = pt.tagId )
Where p.postTypeId = 2 
    And t.tagName = '##TagName##'
Group By DatePart(hh, CreationDate)
```